# Replacing on/off switch in 1960/70's (ish) metal gooseneck lamp (U.K.)

Tags: voltage

I'm in england - the uk?*

I'm not sure if I should post this here, it is hardly electrical engineering, but I'm not sure where else to put it.

The switch on my bedside lamp has died. I've taken it apart and I think the mechanical action has worn the parts out.  It seems to work by twisting a plastic part with copper contacts on each press so that it either makes contact or breaks contact.

[image]

[image]

Does the 2/250 on the back mean 2 amperes 250V?

I've searched online for a guide to the symbols on the back but had no luck.

Can anyone tell me what they mean or point me in the direction of a guide? I'm not sure what to search for to find such a thing.

Would [this be a suitable](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/204042399211?hash=item2f81dfedeb:g:YN8AAOSwS9pZd2fT) replacement?   It has a CE certification mark.

Does anyone know where I would get a more similar replacement?

*It's (Contraction of It is) formatted this way in order to give JRE some editing - something to be pedantic about. ;‑)

Comment: Your assumption could be correct. What kind of lamp is switched with the switch? If it is under 500W, this should fit.

Comment: Same as this one? https://www.lampsandlights.co.uk/shop/inline-switches-plugs/in-line-button-switch/

Comment: Thanks very much Winny. Dim's are 30mm(h) x 20mm(l) x 12mm (w)

Comment: 'formatted this way in order to give [username] some editing' -- I think this is a little rude.  My own questions have been edited for grammatical errors from time to time by several members in good standing.  They are not being "pedantic" when they do so.  They are simply spending their own free time (unpaid) to make some improvements to your question in order to bring it up to a customary standard of quality for EE.SE.  They would not bother to do so unless your Q had some merit to begin with.  I take it as a compliment when such edits are made.

Comment: I've used the switch in the link to replace that very common item more than once. The old ones often had luminous (glow in the dark) push buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very possible that the 2/250 marking denotes a 2A 250V maximum rating. That seems reasonable for use in a simple gooseneck lamp with a low wattage bulb. The potential replacement part you linked to is most likely suitable to operate the lamp provided the mechanical configuration matches close enough. A bit of caution though, many of the markings on the original part are safety agency approvals, if you want to maintain such approval rating for the lamp you should find a replacement part with at least the approval rating applicable for your country, (for example in the USA such a rating would be UL or CSA). It is not clear from the description if the replacement part carries such safety ratings. If you wanted to be sure of this than you might want to purchase the part from a local electrical/hardware store where you could verify such information. This may not be much of a factor for an appliance for your own personal use, however if you might have any potential liabilities, such as renting out your flat (apartment/house) you should use a replacement part with the appropriate approval ratings. If someone were to be injured due to a faulty appliance that you repaired you may be personally liable and subject to legal action.

Comment: Thanks Nedd.  I'm in England.  I searched for old certification marks but couldn't find anything. I'm not too bothered about a lack of results. I asked more out of interest. The replacement is pretty much an exact match, dimensions wise; 1mm out on one side. The replacement I showed has a CE mark which is the European Union certification mark so I should be fine. I am doing it for my personal use, but I'd rather have certified parts since it's a full metal lamp. Thanks again

Comment: Online only stores do sometimes(quite often) sell electrical products with a fake CE mark.  It is usually better to buy electrical products from a known local store, be it a small hardware/electrical store around the corner or a local(in country) big box/everything store(their online should be safe also).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where you are located, but in the US we have mega-hardware stores such as Home Depot and Lowes.  In the Lighting section they have a collection of lamp parts.  A rotary switch is more common than a push-push switch, so you might have to adjust your habits.

There probably is one with approx. the same body size and bushing diameter.  The ones I have have wires pre-attached, so you would connect these to the lamp wiring with small wire nuts.  It might get crowded in there, but you can cut off the switch wires extra wire length.

Comment: Thanks AnalogKid. I'm in the UK, so no Lowes or Home Depot.